# Two Sequences on one column

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, sql-server-2014

You can use 1 or 2 sequence.

Let's say I have a table `tblOrder` and 2 columns in it, `OrderID` and `Company`. I only use two companies in my table, `IBM` and `Airtel`.

What I want is when  `Company` = `IBM` then `OrderID` insert as 1 and when `company` is `Airtel` then it should insert `OrderID` as 1001 and repeat steps with increment 1, meaning next `OrderID` for `IBM` should be 2 and for `Airtel` should be 1002.

I think I need to use two sequences, on one column with case expression.

Comment: Why does the actual value of `OrderID` matter? And what is your question anyway?

Comment: Will there be a UNIQUE INDEX or constraint or PK on this OrderID field? If yes, then what happens when IBM gets to 1000 orders?

Comment: You could write conditional 'nextval' in the default, which requires to read the value of the company name in the script.

Answer (score 4):

Create two [sequences](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff878058(v=sql.110).aspx), one for IBM and one for Airtel. Set the start points appropriately. Put all the logic in a stored procedure. Pick the right one for each INSERT.

This is not a great design. Surrogate keys like this are best if they are completely meaningless. By tying a range of values to a customer you may have problems in the future. What will you do when a range is exhausted? What if you acquire another customer? Will you tolerate gaps in the sequence? For a short-lived, single-purpose application you may be OK. For an enterprise application it is a risk.